# how to create and destroy non blocking sub process that are OS independent in python?

Tags: python

- In a python script i want to spawn a process that runs a file in the same directory
- I dont want the python script to be blocked by the new process
- Then want to be able to close the spawned process from the script.
- Ontop of it all i need it to be OS independant.

What is the best of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried the subprocess module?

Comment: ive had a bit of a play round, maybe not enough. always seem to run into the issue of the process being blocking or not correctly getting the pid

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Comment: i cant recall all of what i tried off hand, as i was at another machine while trying it. 
mostly was playing round with the call and Popen methods

Answer (score 1):

As @Keith suggested use subprocess module, but more specifically use Popen. For example, on Windows, this opens myfile.txt with notepad and then terminates it after a 20 seconds:

```
import subprocess
import time

command = "notepad myfile.txt"
pipe = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False)
time.sleep(5)
pipe.poll()
print("%s" % pipe.returncode)   #"None" when working fine
time.sleep(5)
pipe.terminate()
pipe.wait()
print("%s" % pipe.returncode)   # 1 after termination
```